# CosmosDbTrigger filtered for only inserts?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions

I've got a really simple azure Function with a CosmosDbTrigger set up (taken nearly straight from the examples just as a minimal repro):

```
[FunctionName("ProcessEmail")]
public static void Run([CosmosDBTrigger("mydb", "mycollection")]IReadOnlyList<Document> documents, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Verbose("Documents modified " + documents.Count);
    log.Verbose("First document Id " + documents[0].Id);
}
```

This was super simple to set up and works perfectly.

However, in my case I am only interested in being notified when a record is inserted - not when it is updated.

1. Is it possible to have the trigger only occur when a document is inserted?
2. If not, is it possible to tell, per-document, whether it was an insertion or an update that triggered this run?
3. If not, what's my best option here? Have a flag on the document for whether or not this phase of it has been processed?

Comment: For now I would say to add a field like "docstate" as "new" while inserting and process the doc only if that field value is new. This is my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar requirement for an update-only CosmosDB trigger in one of our function apps. However, we ended up using a flag since controlling the change feed is not yet supported according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed#change-feed-and-different-operations).

> Today, you see all operations in the change feed. The functionality
>   where you can control change feed, for specific operations such as
>   updates only and not inserts is not yet available. You can add a “soft
>   marker” on the item for updates and filter based on that when
>   processing items in the change feed.